# Creating a hash map with sorted linked list in each slot

Tags: c++, hashtable, singly-linked-list

I have successfully made a hash map with chaining and singly linked list in each slot. When I use insert it sends the new node to the back of each linked list, however I need to have each slot be sorted when I insert a new node. How can I edit the following `insert` function so that instead of having to sort each slot afterwards it will insert it in the correct spot to begin with?

```
void hashInsert(int key){
    int hashLoc = h(key);
    HashNode* prev = NULL;
    HashNode* entry = hTable[hashLoc];
    while(entry != NULL){
        prev = entry;
        entry = entry->next;
    }
    if(entry == NULL){
        entry = new HashNode(key);
        if(prev == NULL){
            hTable[hashLoc] = entry;
        }
        else{

            prev->next = entry;
        }
    }
    else{
        entry->value = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add it to the last location of the link, just add it before the node that has a bigger value than it. You can use a comparison function or lambda for this instead of less or bigger than operator. You still need to allocate new HashNode for it and set the next pointer value of the node before to it and set the next value of it to the next node right after. one to the node after.

Comment: What would I set the new HashNode i have to create to equal?

Comment: the key you are adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main trick for keeping each slot sorted is to insert in the correct location, which in this case would be right before the first larger value.

In your code, you enforce inserting at the end of the list with the following while loop.

```
while(entry != NULL){
    prev = entry;
    entry = entry->next;
}
```

Instead, we want to modify this condition so that instead of simply looking for the end of the list (entry == NULL), we also look for a larger value.

```
while(entry != NULL && entry->value < value_to_insert){
    prev = entry;
    entry = entry->next;
}
```

This modified for loop correctly pinpoints the correct place to put your new entry, right between `prev` and `entry`.

Another issue in this case is that your insertion logic has a couple of bugs in it.

This is your insertion logic:

```
if(entry == NULL){
    entry = new HashNode(key);
    if(prev == NULL){
        hTable[hashLoc] = entry;
    }
    else{

        prev->next = entry;
    }
}
else{
    entry->value = key;
}
```

The main issue is that the logic is invalid for the else branch of the `if(entry==NULL)` if statement.

In that case, you need to create a new entry, fix the prev pointers and also fix the next pointers.

It would actually be simpler to rewrite this to the following:

```
new_entry = new HashNode(key);
new_entry->value = value_to_insert;
if(prev == NULL){
    hTable[hashLoc] = new_entry;
}
else{
    prev->next = new_entry;
}

new_entry->next = entry;
```

Comment: In the last link of code, where you have `entry->prev`, I have no `prev` in hash node since I'm using  a singly linked list.

Comment: Oops, my mistake.

Comment: awesome, that works perfectly. I see now how it sets the next  of the new entry to the entry that is currently there already. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay now that I have correctly implemented the insert, it is now not deleting correctly